# Rails observer causing ajax time-out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, observers, faye

I've created an observer to send a "notification" message with faye sever in ROR 4. In development  on my localhost works fine but in production on my EC2 the observer is failing at some point and, what I can't understand, **it's preventing the active record which is observing to be saved.**

Here is my observer:

```
class NotificationObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

require 'eventmachine'



def after_save(notification)
@user = '2'
@channel = '/notifications/2'
@count = '0'

    EM.run {

        client = Faye::Client.new('http://domain.com:9292/faye')    

        publication = client.publish( @channel , {'noti' => 'hello world', 'count' => '0' } )



        publication.callback do
          puts 'Message received by server!'
        end

        publication.errback do |error|
          puts 'There was a problem: ' + error.message
        end


}



end

end
```

I've read about callbacks issues but in development is working fine and I've tested the 'publish' action inside rails console sending the notification with the callbacks and it succeed. 
I've also tried to connect to faye's live server on ec2 from localhost within a copy of the app an it worked as expected, we might can discard faye server too.

So it has to be related with de after_save trigger. What I can't understand is why is preventing the record to be saved since it's an after event trigger. It should start executing after the record is saved, right?

In localhost I'm using apache2 + thin inside ubuntu 14 and in my ec2 I'm running the app throught nginx and unicorn, inside ubuntu 14 too. May be I'm missing some unicorn or nginx configuration that differs from apache2's &/or thin's. .

Update: [Notification now saving, but ajax ends with time-out]

From what I've learned from @lazus-lazaritis link I've changed 'after_save' for 'after_commit' and use logger instead of put to catch the response if there's any error. Now the notification is saved and "publication.callback" achieves success and I get the "a-ok" in the log, but the ajax connection opened by the form that triggered all the action, still ending with a 504 Gateway Time-out.

Here's the updated observer:

```
class NotificationObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

require 'eventmachine'



def after_commit(notification)
    @user = '2'
    @channel = '/notifications/2'
    @count = '0'

        EM.run {

            client = Faye::Client.new('http://domain.com:9292/faye')



            publication = client.publish( @channel , {'noti' => 'hola', 'count' => '0' } )



            publication.callback do
              Rails.logger.debug("a-ok")
            end

            publication.errback do |error|
              Rails.logger.error( 'There was a problem: ' + error.message)
            end


    }



end
```

end

Here is the the controller

```
def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @like = current_user.likes.build(article_params)
    @user_id = current_user.id

    if @like.save

        @notification = Notification.new(user_id: @article.user.id, stype: 'like_article', actor_id: @user_id, action_id: @like.id)
        @notification.save                          
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @article }
            format.js
        end

    else
        flash[:success] = "Ya te gusta!"
        redirect_to @article
    end
end
```

I can't understand why ajax responds with time-out if:

- All the processes before the observer fires are done, notification saving which failed before, too.
- The EM.run inside the observer logs in the production.log the ok response, so callbacks are working fine after_commit

What am I missing ?

This is the unicorn.stderr log:

> E, [2015-09-16T17:56:40.096133 #15731] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:16910 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
>
> E, [2015-09-16T17:56:40.102198 #15731] ERROR -- : reaped # worker=1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your after callback raises an exception then read the following:

> The whole callback chain is wrapped in a transaction. If any before callback method returns exactly false or raises an exception, the execution chain gets halted and a ROLLBACK is issued; after callbacks can only accomplish that by raising an exception.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks that showed me some light but I can't still make it work,